# PHP Binding PDO arrays

Tags: php, oop, pdo, associative-array

I am trying to assemble a database insert with PDO through an array but am just missing it somewhere and am looking for some help on what I'm missing. The array is an associative array. Error thrown is:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught exception \'PDOException\' with message \'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens\' in /var/www/html/themonastery.org/mot/receiver.php:70
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/themonastery.org/mot/receiver.php(70): PDOStatement->execute()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/themonastery.org/mot/receiver.php on line 70
```

Code I'm using is:

```
    /** PDO Stuff **/

    //require and instantiate pdo instance
    require_once "dependancies/pdo.func.php";
    $dbh = pdo_connect();

    //implode query
    $keys = implode(',', array_keys($clean));
    $vals = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($clean), '?'));
    
    $insert = array_values($clean);

    //pdo prepare
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO backupDB ($keys) VALUES ($vals)");

    //set loop condition
    $waiting = true; 
    while($waiting) {
        try {
        $dbh->beginTransaction();

        $i=1;
        foreach($clean as $insert) {

            // bindvalue is 1-indexed, so $k+1
            $sth->bindValue($i++, $insert, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            $sth->execute();
            sleep(1);
        }
        
        $dbh->commit();
        $waiting = false;

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
        if(stripos($e->getMessage(), 'DATABASE IS LOCKED') !== false) {
            //sleep for 0.25 seconds and try again.
            $dbh->commit();
            usleep(250000);
        } else {
            $dbh->rollBack();
            throw $e;
        }
        }
    }
```

Here's the associative array,

```
array (
  'full_name' => 'First Middle Last Suffix',
  'first_name' => 'First',
  'middle_name' => 'Middle',
  'last_name' => 'Last Suffix',
  'address' => 'The Address',
  'city' => 'City',
  'state' => 'State Abbr',
  'zip' => 'Zip code',
  'country' => 'Country Abbr',
  'email' => 'dev@null.com',
  'password' => 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e',
  'ordinationDate' => '2012-04-15',
  'birthday' => '1982-14-01',
  'isValidAge' => '1',
)
```

And by request here's a var_dump of `$keys` and `$vals`

```
$keys = string(123) "full_name,first_name,middle_name,last_name,address,city,state,zip,country,email,password,ordinationDate,birthday,isValidAge"
$vals = string(27) "?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?"
```

Here's the column names from the DB

```
    id  full_name   first_name  middle_name last_name   address city    state   zip country email   password    ordinationDate  birthday    isValidAge  sex timestamp   ulc_edit_time   osc_sync    guid
```

Comment: `var_dump` `$keys` and `$vals`, please.

Comment: `$keys` and `$vals` are ok. Sure all field names are correct?

Comment: I added a copy/paste from the databases' column list for you to look at.

Comment: @GabrielSantos the associative on top is a dump of clean via `var_export`

Comment: see my answer, probably solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
$i=1;
foreach($clean as $insert) {

    // bindvalue is 1-indexed, so $k+1
    $sth->bindValue($i++, $insert, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $sth->execute();
    sleep(1);
}
```

to this:

```
$i=1;
foreach($clean as $insert) {

    // bindvalue is 1-indexed, so $k+1
    $sth->bindValue($i++, $insert, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    sleep(1);
}

$sth->execute();
```

PDO::execute() need to be at the end of all bindValues() (see http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php#example-995)

Additionaly, I have the follow function to bind correct data type (need some changes for your case):

```
public function bindValue($key = null, $value = null) {
    if($key == null) {
        return;
    }

    if(is_int($value)) {
        $param = PDO::PARAM_INT;
    } elseif(is_bool($value)) {
        $param = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
    } elseif(is_null($value)) {
        $param = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
    } elseif(is_string($value)) {
        $param = PDO::PARAM_STR;
    } else {
        $param = FALSE;
    }

    $this->_query->bindValue($key, $value, $param);
}
```